# Rails Novice Struggling to Start Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run rails s, I receive the following errors:

```
/Users/User/application-name/config/initializers/s3_config.rb:3:in `read': No such file or directory - /Users/User/application-name/config/amazon_s3.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/User/application-name/config/initializers/s3_config.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/application-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /Users/User/application-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/User/application-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/User/application-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/User/application-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/User/application-name/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/application-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/User/application-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/User/application-name/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/User/application-name/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/User/application-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your /Users/User/application-name/config/initializers/s3_config.rb file you are attempting to read a /Users/User/application-name/config/amazon_s3.yml that does not exist.

Create your /Users/User/application-name/config/amazon_s3.yml and put your credentials in it